# Selenium dragging a slider that changes after click

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to automate sliding element using selenium and python.

I encountered a problem such as an element that I want to drag is changing after the click and I am having a stale element reference

> "Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document"

```
    element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#section_pickup > div.area__content > div.ng-scope > div.overlay-grey.ng-scope > div > div:nth-child(2) > div > div.ng-scope.pickup-shown-wrapper > div > span > span.irs-slider.to')
    actions.drag_and_drop_by_offset(element,-50,0)
```

This is the slider structure

```
<div
  ewf-pickup-slider="pickupWindowCtrl.rangeSliderOptions"
  class="ng-isolate-scope"
>
  <span class="irs js-irs-0 irs-with-grid"
    ><span class="irs"
      ><span class="irs-line" tabindex="-1"
        ><span class="irs-line-left"></span><span class="irs-line-mid"></span
        ><span class="irs-line-right"></span></span
      ><span class="irs-min" style="display: none; visibility: hidden">0</span
      ><span class="irs-max" style="display: none; visibility: hidden">1</span
      ><span
        class="irs-from"
        data-content="Earliest"
        style="visibility: visible; left: -2.12418%"
        >12:00</span
      ><span
        class="irs-to"
        data-content="Latest"
        style="visibility: visible; left: 95.5882%"
        >18:00</span
      ><span class="irs-single" style="visibility: hidden; left: 42.8105%"
        >12:00 — 18:00</span
      ></span
    ><span class="irs-grid" style="width: 97.7124%; left: 1.04379%"
      ><span class="irs-grid-pol" style="left: 0%"></span
      ><span
        class="irs-grid-text js-grid-text-0"
        style="left: 0%; margin-left: -2.94118%"
        >12:00</span
      ><span class="irs-grid-pol small" style="left: 20%"></span
      ><span class="irs-grid-pol small" style="left: 15%"></span
      ><span class="irs-grid-pol small" style="left: 10%"></span
      ><span class="irs-grid-pol small" style="left: 5%"></span
      ><span class="irs-grid-pol" style="left: 25%"></span
      ><span
        class="irs-grid-text js-grid-text-1"
        style="left: 25%; visibility: visible; margin-left: -2.94118%"
        >13:30</span
      ><span class="irs-grid-pol small" style="left: 45%"></span
      ><span class="irs-grid-pol small" style="left: 40%"></span
      ><span class="irs-grid-pol small" style="left: 35%"></span
      ><span class="irs-grid-pol small" style="left: 30%"></span
      ><span class="irs-grid-pol" style="left: 50%"></span
      ><span
        class="irs-grid-text js-grid-text-2"
        style="left: 50%; visibility: visible; margin-left: -2.94118%"
        >15:00</span
      ><span class="irs-grid-pol small" style="left: 70%"></span
      ><span class="irs-grid-pol small" style="left: 65%"></span
      ><span class="irs-grid-pol small" style="left: 60%"></span
      ><span class="irs-grid-pol small" style="left: 55%"></span
      ><span class="irs-grid-pol" style="left: 75%"></span
      ><span
        class="irs-grid-text js-grid-text-3"
        style="left: 75%; visibility: visible; margin-left: -2.94118%"
        >16:30</span
      ><span class="irs-grid-pol small" style="left: 95%"></span
      ><span class="irs-grid-pol small" style="left: 90%"></span
      ><span class="irs-grid-pol small" style="left: 85%"></span
      ><span class="irs-grid-pol small" style="left: 80%"></span
      ><span class="irs-grid-pol" style="left: 100%"></span
      ><span
        class="irs-grid-text js-grid-text-4"
        style="left: 100%; margin-left: -2.94118%"
        >18:00</span
      ></span
    ><span
      class="irs-bar"
      style="cursor: ew-resize; left: 1.14379%; width: 97.7124%"
    ></span
    ><span class="irs-shadow shadow-from" style="display: none"></span
    ><span class="irs-shadow shadow-to" style="display: none"></span
    ><span class="irs-slider from" style="left: 0%"></span
    ><span class="irs-slider to" style="left: 97.7124%"></span></span
  ><input
    type="text"
    ewf-range-slider="pickupSliderCtrl.sliderOptions"
    class="ng-isolate-scope irs-hidden-input"
    readonly=""
  />
</div>
```

I want to drag and drop `<span class="irs-slider to" style="left: 97.7124%">` which is changing it's classes and style on click

Is there a way to slide it using selenium?

Comment: please add website link

Comment: Unfortunatelly I can't. You have to be logged in and provide several additional data to be able to acces the slider

Comment: i'm not sure about selenium, but i'd give simulating a mouse click and drag a try :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
webdriver.ActionChains(driver).click_and_hold(sliderelement).move_by_offset(100, 0).perform()
```

use click_and_hold and move by offset, you should click on the slider element